# C++ lib in Python: custom sorting method

Tags: python, c++, sorting

I want to make a custom sorting method in C++ and import it in Python. I am not an expert in C++, here are implementation of "sort_counting"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

const int MAX = 30;

class cSort
{
public:
    void sort( int* arr, int len )
    {
        int mi, mx, z = 0; findMinMax( arr, len, mi, mx );
        int nlen = ( mx - mi ) + 1; int* temp = new int[nlen];
        memset( temp, 0, nlen * sizeof( int ) );

        for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) temp[arr[i] - mi]++;

        for( int i = mi; i <= mx; i++ )
        {
            while( temp[i - mi] )
            {
                arr[z++] = i;
                temp[i - mi]--;
            }
        }

        delete [] temp;
    }

private:
    void findMinMax( int* arr, int len, int& mi, int& mx )
    {
        mi = INT_MAX; mx = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
        {
            if( arr[i] > mx ) mx = arr[i];
            if( arr[i] < mi ) mi = arr[i];
        }
    }
};

int main( int* arr )
{
    cSort s;
    s.sort( arr, 100 );

    return *arr;
}
```

and then using it in python

```
from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('sort_counting.so')

result = lib.main([3,4,7,5,10,1])
```

compilation goes nice

How to rewrite a C++ method to receive an array and then return a sorted array?

Comment: Why are you not using Python's sort?

Comment: In C++, you normally use `std::vector` for arrays. You can pass these to and return them from functions, like you would in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is quite clear: `ctypes` doesn't know how to convert a python list into a `int *` to be passed to your function. In fact a python integer is **not** a simple `int` and a `list` is **not** just an array.

There are limitations on what `ctypes` can do. Converting a generic python `list` to an array of `int`s is **not** something that can be done automatically.

This is explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ctypes.html#calling-functions):

> **`None`, integers, bytes objects and (unicode) strings are the only
>   native Python objects that can directly be used as parameters in these
>   function calls.** `None` is passed as a C `NULL` pointer, bytes objects and
>   strings are passed as pointer to the memory block that contains their
>   data (`char *` or `wchar_t *`). Python integers are passed as the
>   platforms default C `int` type, their value is masked to fit into the C
>   type.

If you want to pass an integer array you should read about [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ctypes.html#arrays). Instead of creating a list you have to create an array of ints using the `ctypes` data types and pass that in instead.

Note that you **must** do the conversion from python. It doesn't matter what C++ code you write. The alternative way is to use the Python C/API instead of `ctypes` to only write C code.

---

A simple example would be:

```
from ctypes import *
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('sort_counting.so')

data = [3,4,7,5,10,1]

arr_type = c_int * len(data)
array = arr_type(*data)

result = lib.main(array)

data_sorted = list(result)
```

Comment: Thx. How you may change a cpp main function? now i got malloc: *** mmap(size=18446744066242793472) failed (error code=12)

Comment: @pasichnyk.oleh That's a different error. I suggest you open a new question regarding that.